# Escribir en el mismo lugar

Tags: python-2.7, print

Necesito hacer un contador que sobreescriba el resultado, que lo haga siempre en el mismo lugar, es decir que un número reemplace al anterior. Supongo debe ser muy simple, pero no doy con la solución.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola danielfelix, si he entendido lo que buscas es relativamente simple, eso en la consola se consigue usando el retorno de carro `\r`, `curses` es otra opción para situaciones más complejas. No obstante deberías colocar tu código o al menos la parte correspondiente y explicar detalladamente el resultado que esperas como te han comentado. No es lo mismo que en la terminal solo quieras mostrar el número que se actualiza limpiándola antes de mostrar el contador, que quieras mostrar el número y otra parte estática de texto... Intenta detallar mejor la pregunta.

Comment: for i in range (0,8):
 print (i)   Necesito que en la pantalla se vea un solo número, y no toda la secuencia de números, es tan sencillo y tan difícil de explicarlo...

Comment: `print(i, end='\r')` como te han dicho

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí tu pregunte, pero pondre este codigo aver si te sirve ....

```
for i in range (0,8):
    UltimoNumero=i
```

print(UltimoNumero)

Comment: Quiero que se vean todos los números del 1 al 8, secuencialmente uno sobre el otro, primero ver 1, después 2 en el mismo lugar, despues 3 en el mismo... y así. De hecho hay un sleep en el medio. O sea, el  1 es reemplazado por el dos, el dos por el 3....